# Textbox Binding to both LostFocus and Property Update

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, textbox, prism

Currently I bind to my `TextBox`es as:

```
Text="{Binding DocValue,
         Mode=TwoWay,
         ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

This works great in getting every keystroke to do button status checking (which I want).

In addition, I  would like to track the `LostFocus` event on the `TextBox` (through binding) and do some additional calculations that might be too intensive for each keystroke.

Anyone have thoughts on how to accomplish both?

Comment: you could use `TextBox.OnLostFocus` event

Comment: I think he is wanting to bind a property to the LostFocus, which I don't know if this can be done

Comment: Yeah I was hoping for a way to have my ViewModel do some calculations on LostFocus along with keeping the property updated as they type.  

Going to try and see how much of a delay I get if I just compute as they type.. might look bad as other numbers change based on what they type.

Comment: You can't set two UpdateSourceTriggers, you'll have to use the event LostFocus and update the ViewModel from your code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a solution... I created a composite command and use that for the additional communication.

Command definition

```
public static CompositeCommand TextBoxLostFocusCommand = new CompositeCommand();
```

My textbox

```
private void TextboxNumeric_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Commands.TextBoxLostFocusCommand.RegisteredCommands.Count > 0)
    {
        Commands.TextBoxLostFocusCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

then in my ViewModel, I create a Delegate Command and wire to it..

It seems like it is working, wonder if there is a better way. One downfall to this is that every Textbox will fire this, not just my items that are attached to formulas I want to calculate. Might need to think of ways to improve on this.

Comment: You can probably add a command behavior to the textbox. And only attach to textboxes that require that behavior.

Comment: I added a custom binding property to my textbox that gets set when I want this behavior on (off by default).  Seems to be working

Answer (score 23):

Bind a command to the `TextBox` `LostFocus` event.

XAML

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<TextBox Margin="0,287,0,0">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LostFocusCommand}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

View Model

```cs
private ICommand lostFocusCommand;

public ICommand LostFocusCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (lostFocusCommand== null)
        {
            lostFocusCommand= new RelayCommand(param => this.LostTextBoxFocus(), null);
        }
        return lostFocusCommand;
     }
}

private void LostTextBoxFocus()
{
    // do your implementation            
}
```

you have to reference `System.Windows.Interactivity` for this. And you have to install a redistributable to use this library. you can download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801)

Answer (score 5):

To supplement the highest voted answer, dotnet core has migrated the interactivity library. Steps to get this working:

> 1. Remove reference to "Microsoft.Expression.Interactions" and "System.Windows.Interactivity"
> 2. Install the "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf" NuGet package.
> 3. XAML files – replace the xmlns namespaces "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" and "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"with "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
> 4. C# files – replace the usings in c# files "Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" and "Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions" with "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors"

via [blog (Dec 2018) post here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/)