# How to use LostFocus as a Command in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to use LostFocus event as Command in DataGridTextColumn and can't find an example on how to use it in WPF.
Can anyone help me use it as I am new to WPF.

Thank you.

My xaml looks like:

```
   `

    The c# code:
          public partial class Myogg : UserControl    {
          MyLogg _viewModel;
         public MyLogg()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              _viewModel = new MyLoggUCViewModel();
              DataContext = _viewModel;
          }
        }`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textbox Binding to both LostFocus and Property Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488033/textbox-binding-to-both-lostfocus-and-property-update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use interaction triggers to do this ..

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=LostFocusCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Is still doesn't work. I created a propriety LostFocusCommand which it is never fired.

Comment: public ICommand LostFocusCommand { get { return _saveRowCommand ?? (_lostFocusCommand = new LostFocusCommand()); } }     and the class   LostFocusCommand looks like: public class SaveRowCommand:ICommand
    {

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter) 
        {
            
            MessageBox.Show("LostFocus")
        }
    }